# how to define IP subnet's status using api

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I got subnet's detail information using api but i don't know how to decide status & description of subnet .

[softlayer control's subnet detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF4JM.png)
/ [my page's subnet detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rJfU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following rest request:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet/$subnetId/getIpAddresses?objectMask=mask[guestNetworkComponentBinding]

Method: Get
```

Replace: $user, $apiKey and $subnetId with your own information

This is the logic for:

**Status:**

If the "guestNetworkComponentBinding" is not empty, the status is "In Use"

**Description:**

If the ""guestNetworkComponentBinding" is not empty, the description is "Primary IP"

**References:**

- [SoftLayer_Network_Subnet::getIpAddresses](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet/getIpAddresses)