# Softlayer API: How to get the static subnet belongs to which VSI?

Tags: python, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

## background

I can get a vlan's subnet info by the flowing python script:

```
# Declare an Object Mask to get additional information
    object_mask = 'mask[primaryRouter,subnets[id,billingItem,cidr,version,addressSpace,subnetType,networkIdentifier,totalIpAddresses,usableIpAddressCount,ipAddresses[ipAddress, isReserved, virtualGuest, hardware]]]'
    # Declare an Object Filter to get information from specific vlan
    filter = {'networkVlans': {'id': {'operation': vlan_id}}}
    return self.sl_account.getNetworkVlans(mask=object_mask, filter=filter)[0]
```

And the result contains:

```
[... 'subnets': [{'cidr': 28,
              'id': 986245,
              'billingItem': {'allowCancellationFlag': 1,}
              orderItemId': 223126909,
              'ipAddresses': [{'ipAddress': '169.38.73.xxx', ...
               'subnetType': 'STATIC_IP_ROUTED',
             'totalIpAddresses': '8',
             'usableIpAddressCount': '5',
             'version': 4},
             ...]
            }
            ...
            ]]
```

## question

The result of STATIC_IP_ROUTED subnet do not contain the  virtualGuest item.

1. Now I want to know which VSI has bind this subnet?  Does any other mask can helps?
2. Or, How can I get the secondary ip info of a vsi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add the subnets relational property to go deeper and display the VSI on  which the subnet is binded through the property **endpointIpAddress**.

Please try your code with the mask previously mentioned:

```
# Declare an Object Mask to get additional information
object_mask = 'mask[primaryRouter,subnets[id,billingItem,cidr,version,addressSpace,subnetType,networkIdentifier,totalIpAddresses,usableIpAddressCount,ipAddresses[id, ipAddress, virtualGuest[id], hardware[id]]], subnets[endPointIpAddress[id,ipAddress,subnet[id, datacenter[longName,name]],hardware[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName],virtualGuest[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName]]]]'

# Declare an Object Filter to get information from specific vlan
filter = {'networkVlans': {'id': {'operation': vlan_id}}}

return self.sl_account.getNetworkVlans(mask=object_mask, filter=filter)[0]
```

Or you may use the **SoftLayer_Account::getSubnets** method.

```
# Declare an Object Mask to get additional subnet information
object_mask = 'mask[id, networkIdentifier, subnetType, totalIpAddresses, datacenter[longName, name], networkVlan[id, vlanNumber], endPointIpAddress[id,ipAddress,subnet[id, datacenter[longName,name]],hardware[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName],virtualGuest[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName]]]'

# Declare an Object Filter to get information from specific Subnet.
filter = {"subnets":{"id":{"operation":subnet_id}}}

subnetsResult = client ['Account'].getSubnets(filter = filter, mask = object_mask)

print(subnetsResult)
```

On both solutions you will see the VirtualGuest item information.

In order to retrieve the secondary ip Addresses of a VSI please refer to this post [How to get secondary ip addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44816160/softlayer-api-how-to-get-secondary-addresses-of-virtual-machine/44893647#44893647).